# Remove empty positions in array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, hashmap

I've created the following method:

```
def list_all_keys
$hash_table
keys=[]
output_file = File.open("output.txt", "w")
output_file.write("Hash Table: \n")
for i in 0..$hash_table.length - 1
  current_node = $hash_table[i]
  puts current_node.val
  while current_node.val != -1
    keys.push("key:" + current_node.key.to_s + ", value:" + current_node.val.to_s + ". pos:" + current_node.pos.to_s)
    current_node = current_node.next
  end
  puts "Hash:" + i.to_s + ", Entries:" + keys.to_s
  output_file.write("Hash:" + i.to_s + ", Entries:" + keys.to_s + "\n")
  keys = []
end
output_file.close
end
end
```

To write a file `output.txt` which would contain a hash map of all the values but my output includes a lot of empty positions (because of the while loop, I think).

Example of output:

```
Hash:3964, Entries:[]    /// CAN THESE BE PREVENTED? ///
Hash:3965, Entries:["key:quicker., value:1. pos:[3573]"]
Hash:3966, Entries:["key:easily, value:2. pos:[5639, 10510]"]
Hash:3967, Entries:["key:kept, value:6. pos:[1732, 1785, 3392, 5932, 7544, 9047]"]
Hash:3968, Entries:[]
Hash:3969, Entries:[]
```

Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: Are you wanting to just not output the empty keys?  Then just use 'unless keys.empty?' after the puts / output

Comment: @JLB I don't want them to be written to the file, also

Comment: output_file.write("Hash:" + i.to_s + ", Entries:" + keys.to_s + "\n") unless keys.empty?

Comment: actually, before printing / output to file, just write 'next if keys.empty?'

Comment: @JLB got it. If you can write this as an answer then I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your code isn't syntactically correct.

Comment: What is `$hash_table` doing in there? Global variables like that should be avoided unless there's absolutely no alternative to them. Is that intended to be part of the method signature?

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before your `puts "Hash" ...` line you can write `next if keys.empty?;`

This will skip to the next iteration of the loop.

By the way, if you want to remove any nil elements of an array, you can use `flatten`.

I.e. `[nil, 2, 3, nil ].flatten` will equal `[2,3]`